# svn list local directory for svn URL

Tags: svn

I'm using tortoise svn clien on my local PC. I have one directory i.e. c:\temp\svn\ where are located several checked out directories. For simplicity let's say the strucutre is as this: 
c:\temp\svn\project1 - svn://192.168.1.3/home-repo-1/
c:\temp\svn\project2 - svn://192.168.1.3/home-repo-2/

Is there a way how I could find out location of checked out directory based on the svn URL? This means that I want some svn command: svn "get local directory" "svn://192.168.1.3/home-repo-1/"

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.  =/

Why?  Because you can have /many working directories/ checked out of the same repo.   There's not one unique answer to your question in this case - there's a set of directories.

You can see if a specific working dir has a particular URL, however, with the `svn info` command.

If you knew all of your WDs were under a certain path, you could even write a small script to query them all using `svn info` and return a list of those that are roots of a checked out repository - but there is nothing like that which comes standard in svn.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I was afraid that this will be an answer. "svn info" is not a way to go becasue there can be thousands of directories on you disk drive and to scan them all it would the nightmare. I already use script whith "hardcoded" path to checked-out directory; just wanted to have something more idiot proof.

Solution does not have to be necessary related to svn command. Maybe something in registers what I could use? I.e. if you right clik on windows to checked out folder, in properties window is subversion tab ...